# Firestore snapshot listener trigger when deleting element

Tags: android, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with my firebase chat app. For the database part i'm using firestore cloud. The problem is that everytime i delete a message from the database, the message listener triggers twice:

- first with the deletion (i receive a document.REMOVED)
- second with another random message document ADDED

Here is my code for the snapshot listener:

```
chatListener = db.collection(ALL_CHAT)
                .orderBy(SEND_TIME, Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .limit(20)
                .addSnapshotListener((messagesDocumentSnapshot, e) -> {
                    if (!messagesDocumentSnapshot.getDocumentChanges().isEmpty()) {
                        List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
                        messagesDocumentSnapshot.getDocumentChanges().forEach(documentChange -> {
                            if (documentChange.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                                Message message = documentChange.getDocument().toObject(Message.class);
                                message.setId(documentChange.getDocument().getId());       
                                messages.add(message);
                            }
                        });

                        if (!messages.isEmpty()) {
                            Collections.reverse(messages);
                            allChatFragment.updateMessages(messages, POSITION_END);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Here is the code for the delete :

```
db.collection(ALL_CHAT)
                .document(id)
                .delete();
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but since you are listening to last 20 msg [limit(20)] , so when u delete any msg from last 20 msgs you get 21st msg callback as added, can u check if you get callback if you delete some old msg like msg at 40th position.

Answer (score 3):

Your query is saying "give me the top 20 documents ordered by SEND_TIME":

```
chatListener = db.collection(ALL_CHAT)
                .orderBy(SEND_TIME, Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .limit(20)
```

When you attach a listener to it, the listener will be invoked **every** time that **any** document in the top 20 changes over time.

When you delete a document from the top 20, your listener will receive a callback telling you which document was deleted.  And, since your query always wants to the top 20, the listener will be invoke again to tell you that another document is now part of the top 20 (which was previously at position 21).  That will show up as an "added" document.

So, your listener is working as expected.  Your listener should be prepared to handle any of the changes to the top 20 documents at any moment in time.

Answer (score 1):

This is the intended behaviour.

When you delete your document, if it was one of the documents matched by your query, it will be removed from the results of that query and each listener is notified that the value was removed.

Now that your query only matches 19 documents out of the 20 it would like, each listener is notified of a new document that matches your query's selection criteria. When a document is "added", it doesn't mean added/uploaded to the database, but that it is added to the list of results of your query.